# Jquery radio:checked is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jquery. I have made a simple html file with minor validations in jquery , but they are not behaving properly. The issue is:

If Enter name first and then select the checkbox, everything seems to be working fine .

But if I select gender first and then enter name , it keeps alerting me to select gender. 
Is there an issue with the way which the code has been implemented?

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Name").focus();
        $("#target").submit(function () {
            var fn = $("#Name").val();
            if (fn == "" && fn.length == 0) {
                alert('Name is mandatory');
                $("#Name").focus();
                return false;
            }
            var status = false;
            $("#gender").each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":radio:checked")) {
                    status = true;
                }
            });
            if (!status) {
                alert("Select Gender");
                $("#gender").focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
<form id='target' action='MyResult.html'>
    First Name:
    <input type='text' name='Name' id='Name' />
    <br/>Gender:
    <input type='radio' name='gender' id='gender' value='male' />Male
    <input type='radio' name='gender' id='gender' value='female' />Female
    <br/>
    <input type='submit' value='Registration' />
</form>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. I see `id='gender'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique. You can use [Attribute value selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in combination with `:checked` to filter out whether radio button is checked or not.

```
var status = $(":radio[name=gender]:checked").length > 0;
```

instead

```
var status = false;
$("#gender").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":radio:checked")) {
        status = true;
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9sBF7/)